# How do you troubleshoot a connection stability issue on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ethernet

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=118
```

I keep having issues with npm because of connection issues, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot it, I already ran DSVM and scanned for corrupted files, ran the network troubleshooter, installed Windows updates and called my ISP, but nothing. I get a different error every time, but it seems to be related to the connection being unstable. I have a 100 Mbps connection with an ethernet cable, so I am kinda confused.

```
admin@PC-SE-L3056 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/New folder (6)
$ npm install --verbose
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.1.2
npm info using node@v16.13.1
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (6)\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\admin\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 11ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 427ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/critical 526ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer 84ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash 80ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra 96ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 118ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css 121ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime 129ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vinyl 131ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss 134ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws 189ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/filter-css 424ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 1077ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map 63ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/css 73ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs 72ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.reject 76ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.defaults 79ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 82ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isfunction 86ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/picocolors 107ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isstring 141ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/universalify 142ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isregexp 403ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.result 422ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonfile 534ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/critical Completed in 550ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/clean-css Completed in 2ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/debug Completed in 1ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 62ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-resolve 62ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/urix 95ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/filter-css Completed in 104ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/css Completed in 4ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/fs-extra Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/jsonfile Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.defaults Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.isfunction Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.isregexp Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.isstring Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.reject Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/lodash.result Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/postcss Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/picocolors Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/puppeteer Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/mime Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/source-map Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/source-map-resolve Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/universalify Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/urix Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/vinyl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/ws Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/css/node_modules/inherits Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/fs-extra/node_modules/graceful-fs Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/jsonfile/node_modules/graceful-fs Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1746ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 10ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 2187ms
npm timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 2188ms
npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 6ms
npm timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 141ms
npm timing reify:createSparse Completed in 5ms
npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 193ms
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 195ms
npm timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:audit Completed in 196ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.isstring Completed in 235ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.isfunction Completed in 236ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.isregexp Completed in 237ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/ms Completed in 243ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/universalify Completed in 244ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.defaults Completed in 246ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.result Completed in 246ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash.reject Completed in 264ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/jsonfile Completed in 268ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/css/node_modules/inherits Completed in 271ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/filter-css Completed in 288ms
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/urix Completed in 294ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/picocolors Completed in 302ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/vinyl Completed in 310ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 286ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/extract-zip 293ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/atob 304ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/debug Completed in 331ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-extra/node_modules/graceful-fs Completed in 336ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/jsonfile/node_modules/graceful-fs Completed in 339ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp 322ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/source-map-resolve Completed in 366ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/critical Completed in 402ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/mime Completed in 420ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/extract-zip/-/extract-zip-1.7.0.tgz 108ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.7.1.tgz 115ms (cache hit)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/css Completed in 429ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/atob/-/atob-2.1.2.tgz 100ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.5.tgz 98ms (cache hit)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/ws Completed in 488ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 504ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/extract-zip Completed in 515ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/extract-zip/node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 518ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/atob Completed in 528ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inline-critical 597ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/postcss Completed in 632ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-extra Completed in 632ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/source-map Completed in 646ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/oust 620ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inline-critical/-/inline-critical-4.1.2.tgz 36ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/oust/-/oust-0.5.2.tgz 40ms (cache hit)
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/inline-critical Completed in 710ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/oust Completed in 717ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/puppeteer Completed in 724ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/clean-css Completed in 959ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/lodash Completed in 4513ms
npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 4516ms
npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 27ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 3ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/critical Completed in 106ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/inline-critical Completed in 105ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/atob Completed in 106ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/extract-zip Completed in 107ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/filter-css Completed in 106ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/oust Completed in 106ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/mime Completed in 106ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 109ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/extract-zip/node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 116ms
npm timing build:link Completed in 119ms
npm info run puppeteer@2.1.1 install node_modules/puppeteer node install.js
npm info run puppeteer@2.1.1 install { code: 1, signal: null }
npm timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 331ms
npm timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 160ms
npm timing command:install Completed in 7693ms
npm verb stack Error: command failed
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm verb pkgid puppeteer@2.1.1
npm verb cwd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (6)
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--verbose"
npm verb node v16.13.1
npm verb npm  v8.1.2
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (6)\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
npm ERR!       throw err;
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (6)\node_modules\yauzl\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The error you show seems related to path on the C: drive (note fwd an bck slashes, BTW), not network.